# File does not exist: htdocs/error.html

Tags: apache-2.2

I am using Apache to serve Jboss content so there wont be any pages in htdocs all my content will be loaded from JBOSS. But I am getting the following error in access_log log file.

Please suggest me if there is any configuration change can help me in not getting this error.

```
May  6 04:56:54 hrpweb01 logger: [Sun May 06 04:56:54 2012] [error] [client 1.202.218.8] File does not exist: /d01/apache/htdocs/error.html
May  6 05:27:51 hrpweb01 logger: [Sun May 06 05:27:51 2012] [error] [client 150.70.97.41] File does not exist: /d01/apache/htdocs/error.html
May  6 05:32:31 hrpweb01 logger: [Sun May 06 05:32:31 2012] [error] [client 150.70.97.41] File does not exist: /d01/apache/htdocs/error.html
May  6 05:45:34 hrpweb01 logger: [Sun May 06 05:45:34 2012] [error] [client 128.177.42.2] File does not exist: /d01/apache/htdocs/error.html
May  6 05:46:08 hrpweb01 logger: [Sun May 06 05:46:08 2012] [error] [client 128.177.42.2] File does not exist: /d01/apache/htdocs/error.html
May  6 05:53:09 hrpweb01 logger: [Sun May 06 05:53:09 2012] [error] [client 68.108.50.26] File does not exist: /d01/apache/htdocs/error.html
```

I am using Apache/2.2.22 version and mod_jk version is 0.98.

Regards,
Sriharsha Kalluru.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like either your application is sending users an error page, or that you are getting random requests for a non-existent page to your web server.

You really can't do much about non-existent pages, but if the error page is being served correctly, and doesn't exist, that could be the problem.

You may want to examine your Apache configuration files to inspect any directives to the [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) and see what they are pointing to.